# How to transfer files a-la Dropbox with an iPad in a LAN?

Tags: dropbox, ipad

I use Dropbox to transfer file (ebooks, documents, images...) to and from an iPad and 2 ubuntu laptops in the same LAN, but it's a nonsense to move files to the cloud and back again to the same LAN.

Is there a local alternative, such as setting up a samba share, or a ssh/scp/sshfs service, or rsync on the ubuntu pcs, and accessing it via some app on the iPad?

Comment: I think dropbox has a service for LAN sync where downloads and uploads are done only once for files in same network. http://www.dropbox.com/help/137

Comment: LAN sync isn't supported on the iPad (http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=21000).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/owncloud-2-your-personal-cloud-server.html (a software solution) --or--

http://tonido.com/  if you prefer a hardware approach.